# How to remap the Mac power key into forward delete?

Tags: power-management, keyboard-layout, macbook, delete

I have got a Macbook and would like to remap the power key to work as a forward delete like on a common keyboard. Best solution would be that the power key still function as such when long pressing it. Thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What have you already tried?

Comment: I use 22.04 that I have just installed on an Intel  Macbook Air 7,2. I have not tried anything yet. I am looking for some guidance to try something.